# How to navigate from one ListWidget to other ListWidget using QStackedwidget in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui

I am using QStackedWidget class in qt and wanted to move from one list to other list(QListWidget). But i am unable to move.

I have used QStackedWidget class and added both list under it :

```
QStackedWidget *stack = new QStackedWidget();
stack->addWidget(list1);
stack->addWidget(list2);
```

`List1` and `List2` are having diff elements :

```
List1->addItem("Hello");
list1->addItem("Hi");
```

When clicking on Hello ListWidgetItem, it should move to list 2....

Comment: So what have you tried yourself? Have you figured up a slot for your click signal?

Comment: I am new to gt. So will u kndly help me in SIGNAL and SLOT function. What actually i have to write?

Comment: read this doc : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something like this code below.

#### myclass.h

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

    ...

    public slots:
        void swapListWidgets();

    ...

    private:
        QStackedWidget *m_stackedWidget;
}
```

#### myclass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_stackedWidget(new QStackedWidget(this))
{
    QListWidget *listWidget1 = new QListWidget(m_stackedWidget);
    listWidget1->addItem("Hello");
    listWidget1->addItem("Hi");
    QListWidget *listWidget2 = new QListWidget(m_stackedWidget);

    m_stackedWidget->addWidget(listWidget1);
    m_stackedWidget->addWidget(listWidget2);
    ...

    connect(listWidget1, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)), SLOT(swapListWidgets(QListWidgetItem * item)));

    // OR

    connect(m_stackedWidget.index(0), SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem * item)), SLOT(swapListWidgets(QListWidgetItem * item)));

    ...

}

...

MyClass::swapListWidgets(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    if (item.text() == "Hello")
        m_stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(list2);
        // or m_stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1);
}

...
```

Comment: Both list are inside QStackedWidget. SO how to pass them under connect()